# Методы CHtml YII

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая разница между `active` и не `active` методами `CHtml` (например `dropDownList()` и `activeDropDownList()`). Не могу до конца понять. Благодарю.

Comment: Эти методы практически ничем не отличаются. Если использовать второй метод, то к аттрибуту class поля ввода добавится класс, заданный в свойстве errorCss, если в поле ввели некорректные данные данные.

Answer (score 1):

Если ничего не путаю, то обычный [Chtml::dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail) создаёт обычный список по преданным данным.

А [Chtml::activeDropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail) привязан к модели формы, так что вводимые данные будет проще проверить на валидность + имя списка (atribute) должно быть определено в модели формы(наверное это для целостности данных или типа того).
Ещё активные элементы формы умеют генерировать сообщения об ошибках при инвалидных данных.

Answer (score 0):

Отличается входящими параметрами

```
// Если вам нужен селект
CHtml::dropDownList($name,$select,$data,$htmlOptions);

$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array());
// Если вам нужен селект в форме
// внутри будет вызван CHtml::activeDropDownList
$form->dropDownList($model,$attribute,$data,$htmlOptions);
```

Comment: @VasyOk чем отличается print от printf  ? Входящими  параметрами :)

Comment: Ну да, ну да :)